# Adding module.modulemap causes cycle in dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, circular-dependency

I have a static library, `C`, with mix of obj-c and Swift code in it. My main app, target `A` references this library. There are many other dependencies and static libraries also in the project. Since I added `module.modulemap` file to my static library project so I can use it in Swift code in my main app, the project build fails with following error message:

```
error: Cycle in dependencies between targets 'A' and 'C'; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources.
Cycle path: A → B → C → A
Cycle details:
→ Target 'A' has target dependency on Target 'B'
→ Target 'B' has compile command for Swift source files
→ Target 'C' has copy command from 'path_to_project/Resources/module.modulemap' to 'path_to_build_folder/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/{ProjectName}/module.modulemap'
○ Target 'C' has compile command with input 'path_to_target_C/{ProjectName}/Somefile.mm'
○ Target 'C' has compile command for Swift source files
```

It seems it's due to the new `modulemap` file and the copy phase that I added to my static library, but can't tell why that copy phase is adding a dependency cycle.

I have followed steps mentioned in [swift-static-library-in-objective-c](https://paul-samuels.com/blog/2018/01/14/swift-static-library-in-objective-c/) for adding this support.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, you need to go to `Build Phases` and move the copy phase where you copy `module.modulemap` above `Compile Sources`.

[image]

But, still, unclear why the dependency happens in the first place.

If you still were getting the error message after this work, moving the module from static library to static framework helps to mitigate this issue.